# How to store offline images in Flutter

Tags: flutter, offline, desktop

I'm creating a flutter project (Desktop only) that will include creating multiple items with images but the app is completely offline so i have to store the images locally somewhere.

I doubt storing them in a database would be a good idea so what is the alternative?

Should i make a folder and copy all the images that is being added and store the image file path in the database?

Comment: that is how I have just solved this issue. But also interested if there are better solutions

Comment: Try use https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

Comment: In my use case I am not really caching network data but syncing new data upon start-up. So it is more of a offline app that updates in database once per session.

Comment: Same as w461 im not using images from a server. Im just storing some offline images and link them to offline items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it the way I described in my question, and it has been working flawlessly.

Comment: How did you do it? Can you share with me the solution?

Comment: When the app opens for the first time it asks the user to choose a directory to store all the images. 
Then I store the location in a local storage (hive), whenever they add an image, I copy the image to the chosen directory with a unique key as the name and then store the name in my database.
Whenever the app needs to show the image I append the stored image name in the local storage to the chosen directory and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

[This package](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) allows you to cache images you get online and will store them in cache.

Comment: Im aware of that package but my images are not from a server or internet to be exact. Im just storing some offline images and link them to offline items

Answer (score 0):

according to  this package [download_network_images_for_offline: ^0.0.5](https://pub.dev/packages/download_network_images_for_offline)

> NetworkImageForOffline will check for internet access, when it has internet access it will use the networkImage and download the file if it has not been downloaded yet. If internet access is not available it will use the downloaded file, when that file was not installed yet it will show a loading placeholder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You could store them as normal flutter assets.

- Create a folder in the flutter project directory called `assets`
- Put all image into the `assets` directory
- Declare the `assets` folder in your `pubspec.yaml`

You can refer to the [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/assets) for more info.

Comment: I guess he is storing the images after compiling. Assets do not help then

Comment: Yep im adding the images in runtime.

Comment: You can use `path_provider` to save the image locally on the computer, however, the `path` needs to be saved. So you would still need a database. You can use Hive to store the document location.